# Merging of multiple xml files to a single xml file using xslt 2.0 - worked. Having trouble doing the same transformation using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have multiple xml source files with in a folder. By using the below xslt i am able to combine all the xml files to one xml file. This transformation uses "collection" which is available in 2.0.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="inputFolder">file:\C:\Desktop\RD\XSLTransformationTest\SourceXML</xsl:param> 

    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="translate(concat($inputFolder, '\SingleSource.XML'),'\','/')"/>
        <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$filename"/></xsl:message>
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$filename}">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="rootcopy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="rootcopy">
        <xsl:copy>              
            <xsl:variable name="folderURI"  select="$inputFolder"/>     
            <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$folderURI"/></xsl:message>           
            <xsl:for-each select="collection(translate(concat($folderURI, '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'),'\','/'))/*/node()">
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>           
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Deep copy template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Handle default matching -->
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now i am trying to do the same transformation using xslt 1.0. But i get error at collection. How do i achieve this? any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As you would expect, there are things that can be done in XSLT 2.0 that cannot be done in XSLT 1.0. If you need to select files from a folder for XSLT processing, try doing it in your calling application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way in XSLT 1.0 to process more than one XML file is using the `document` function with an argument being an XML document listing the documents you want to process e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="document(document('doc-list.xml')//file/@src)/*/node()"/>` if the file `doc-list.xml` has e.g. `<files><file src="file1.xml"/><file src="file2.xml"/></files>`. You would need to create that particular file with all files to be processed in a directory (structure) outside of XSLT.